# Cmake rerun due to cuda generated files

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I have the following situation: I have a CMake file, which is supposed to compile few binary targets.
And I also have CUDA in my project

```
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_libraries_to_linker
```

When i run my `cmake` everything is fine.
First `make target a` command also runs smooth but second `make` command detects that **cuda generated file older than Makefile** and regenerated cmake that leads to project rebuilding.
How I can disable cmake regeneration?
Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
I think is should edit my question.

I have a Caffe framework, building from sources and binary that uses it.
When i'm enabling GPU - Cuda generates it's files due to compilation `make target a`, so when i run another make target i see something like

> Re-run cmake file: Makefile older than:
>   Caffe/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_cudnn_relu_layer.cu.o.depend

When GPU is off everything is ok - any make commands do not leads to regeneration

Comment: `FindCUDA.cmake` provides a number of special commands, like `cuda_add_executable()`, `cuda_compile()` etc., which are suspiciously absent from the snippet you posted. Please check the documentation of `FindCUDA.cmake` and make sure you followed recommended procedures to make CMake aware of the intricacies of CUDA. Other than that, no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Answer (score 2):

Answer have found in the link below:

Brief: Everything is normal. That's normal behaviour of `FindCUDA.cmake`.

After first make run `.depend` files will be included into CMake project and second make run will recompile without regeneration of `.depend` files.
After second make everything will be okay, and changes in one module will not lead to recompilation in whole project.

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/042173.html